# Number picker on Windows 8.1 App

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8.1, numberpicker

I seem unable to have a simple Decimal box.

Either, via visual scroll wheel like the date picker.

Or a textbox that allows only number input.

Ive attached to the up and down key presses. These do not stop input.

```
 private void TProperty_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
            //e.Handled = IsNumber(((TextBox)sender).Text);
        }
```

Ive also read and tried attaching to `PreviewText` But this does not exist in Windows 8.1 App. (no idea why).

Nor can i find any official control in the documentation.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any such controls in-box, but there are third party spin controls in toolkits such as the [WinRTXamlToolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/)'s NumericUpDown control.

If you want to filter a TextBox yourself then you can do that too. There isn't a way to preprocess the text entered in a TextBox. You'll need to validate it after it has been set on the TextBox.

The best event to validate the text depends on the scenario. I'd probably validate in TextChanged and set a property to report if the TextBox's contents are invalid. This property can drive a warning to the user that the data is invalid and it allows any commit code to disable until the text is valid.

For simple positive integers you can filter out any non-numeric data by checking it in TextChanged, removing invalid characters, and then setting it back. You have to be more careful with more complex data since users will often enter invalid data (e.g. "-") on their way to entering valid data (e.g "-1"). You need to make sure you don't reject temporarily invalid text that could become valid.

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    string text = tb.Text;
    try
    {
        Decimal dec = Decimal.Parse(text);
        TextValid = true;
    }
    catch (System.FormatException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception converting {1} to Decimal {0}", ex,text);
        TextValid = false;
    }
}
```